# Server closed connection error on several browsers when testing SSL

Tags: tls, server

I have uploaded a SSL Certificate to my site [www.walksindorset.co.uk](https://www.walksindorset.co.uk).

When I [test the SSL rating](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walksindorset.co.uk) I receive the error message "Server closed connection" on over 15 browsers which includes Andriod 4.0.4, 4.2.2, 4.3 and IE 6 to IE 8.

I cannot find a solution to this problem. Can anyone help?

I am using a shared hosting package via Fasthosts.

Comment: Could you explain how you are going about testing the SSL rating?   I checked out your website via https:// and it works fine, and I ran it though the following SSL testing site https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.walksindorset.co.uk&latest and did not see any issues..   Your certificates actually get an A+ rating from ssllabs.com, which many banks do not even get that kind of a rating...

Comment: Hi, this is the test results from SSLLABS https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.walksindorset.co.uk

Comment: I have tried to load my site on my wife's android phone and it will not load. I get the error phone message "A secure connection could not be established" and the site won't load

Comment: The results of the SSLLABS are towards the end of the report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several of the browsers that are not supported on that list do not support TLS 1.2, which is the only protocol that your sever is configured to use..

[image]

Here is an example of some of the browsers you are having issues with viewing HTTPs
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I overcome that problem?

Comment: well, those browsers are no longer being updated so thats why they are not supporting TLS 1.2...   You could configure your certificate to allow for the older protocols to be used, but it will weaken the security of your site.    What web server are you using?

Comment: Nowadays, TLS 1.2 is still not supported by many clients, sadly. I would enable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 and reevaluate it eg. in a year or two.

Comment: How do I enable 1.0 and 1.1?

Comment: Are you using apache?  nginx?  what version?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/314858/how-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-with-openssl-and-apache

Comment: FYI if my answer solved your question could you please mark it as such?   There is a little checkbox under the UP/DOWN vote counter that you have to check to make it the solution to your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using apache

Comment: For those on nginx, [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-3-—-configure-tls-ssl-on-web-server-nginx) is a safe setup supporting TLS 1, 1.1 and 1.2 (scroll down to  **Nginx configuration additions — 2 of 3**).

Comment: If I am on a shared hosting account can I get my hosting company to make the changes to the server?